# Error message with Entity Framework keys

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm running EF4.3, database first.

My primary key for users is UserId which I use to relate to all other associated tables.

I have 3 types of users all of which have unique values so they are stored in their own tables. They are, Contributors, Members and Administrators.

A further constraint is placed on these tables using UserId and UserRoleId in the user table and UserId and a fixed UserRoleId in the subordinate tables. For instance, the Members table will have a computed value of '3' which is the UserRoleId of a member. This ensures that a user can only exist in 1 of the subscriber tables at any one time.

EF throws an error in the edmx build because UserRoleId is not part of the primary key of the Users table. Everything seems to work ok but just wondered if there is either something I'm doing wrong or there is anything I can do to circumvent the errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either change the name of UserRoleId since EF thinks it's the PR key or if you want UserRoleId to be a part of key use [Key] on top of the attribute.